# Is it possible to create logical folders not only physical folders in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to create logical folders in visual studio which could have different structures depending on different perspectives so is it possible or are there any addin to do so ? Visual Studio Solutions don't fit this need nor of course Visual Studio Folder since they are just explorer physical folders.

Explorer has Symbolink Links, Hard Links and SoftLinks, woulda kind have the same kind of thing within Visual Studio.

Update: I tried to create a new solution. Problem is that I want to point to files in OTHERS projects so that the file still behave within the same original context (references etc.). If I create a new solution, I'll have much more than just create a shortcut, I'll have to recreate all the context that may be very complex.

Comment: The C++ IDE supports this, they are named "filters".  Not available in other IDEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Solution folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haytww03.aspx) are logical, not physical.

> Solution Folders are an organizational tool in Solution Explorer; corresponding Windows folders are not created.

Comment: Problem is that I want to point to files in OTHERS projects so that the file still behave within the same original context (references etc.). If I create a new solution, I'll have much more than just create a shortcut, I'll have to recreate all the context that may be very complex.

Comment: @user310291 - I am not sure what you are looking for exactly, but you _can_ add a file from a different project as a link. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92.aspx

Comment: Thanks but if they have thought about adding shortcuts they should have thought about adding a whole directory shortcut ! Sometimes I wonder if they don't lack common sense.